# jQuery jCarouselLite fails on sliding two images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, jcarousellite

[JCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/)  is working fine for more than two images.

But for TWO images or li JCarouselLite not working correctly. Last image display again and again.

Any Ideas ?

**HTML**:

```
<div id="explore_slider" style="width:980px !important;height:300px;">
  <ul style="width:980px;height:300px;">
    <li><img src="/images/feature_bicflex4.jpg" width="980px" height="300px" /></li>
    <li><img src="/images/feature_bordeauxwine.jpg" width="980px" height="300px" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#explore_slider").jCarouselLite({
    speed: 1000,
    auto: true
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter `visible: 1`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#explore_slider").jCarouselLite({
  speed: 1000,
  auto: true,
  visible: 1
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks JercSi, its works fine now.  

Here, I also got its documentation for option:visible. currently visible default val is 3. http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/?#doc
 
Best Regards